Extracting path data from an ImageBitmap in Kotlin/Jetpack Compose
I am working on extracting data from a user-drawn signature in my Jetpack Compose Android App. I need to convert a user drawn signature into a format that can be used within an SVG's <path> tag, representing exactly what the user drew.
Goal: Retrieve path data from a user's inputted signature that exactly represents their drawing in the app.
Problem: The current solution provides inaccurate path data that does not accurately represent the user's drawing. Below is an example of what is currently being printed when the user completes drawing a signature:
M 390 294 L 391 294 L 392 294 L 393 294 L 394 294 L 395 294 L 396 294 L 397 294 L 398 294 L 399 294 L 400 294 L 401 294 M 384 295 L 385 295 L 386 295 L 387 295 L 388 295 L 389 295 L 390 295 L 391 295 L 392 295 L 393 295 L 394 295 L 395 295 L 396 295 L 397 295 L 398 295 L 399 295 L 400 295 L 401 295 M 376 296 L 377 296 L 378 29... it goes on for a long time like this (even just for a simple line). When I place the data in an SVG, I sometimes see a bit of the drawn image, but never the whole thing (regardless of the width, height, and viewBox I set).
Current Solution:
I'm using this package for user input. After the user completes their signature, the package returns an ImageBitmap. If I display it to the UI with an Image component, it is correctly represented.
However, when I parse the ImageBitmap using the function below, the resulting SVG path data does not accurately represent the drawn signature when inserted into an actual SVG.
Here is the main code handling the user's input:
var imageBitmap: ImageBitmap? by remember { mutableStateOf(null) }
val state = remember { SignatureState() }
var isLoading by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

Sain(
    state = state,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(159.dp),
    signatureThickness = 2.dp,
    onComplete = { signatureBitmap ->
        if (signatureBitmap != null) {
            imageBitmap = signatureBitmap
        } else {
            println("Signature is empty")
        }
    },
) { action ->
    Row() {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                imageBitmap = null
                action(SignatureAction.CLEAR)
            }) {
                Icon(Icons.Outlined.Delete, contentDescription = "Clear", modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp), tint = Color.Gray)
        }
    }

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            Button(onClick = {
                isLoading = true
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    action(SignatureAction.COMPLETE)
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                        val pathData = extractSVGPath(imageBitmap!!)
                        //print the returned data for testing
                        println(pathData)
                    }
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        isLoading = false
                    }
                }
            },
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            ) {
                if (isLoading) {
                    //show a loading icon
                } else {
                    Text(text = "Add Signature")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

And here's the parsing function that returns the path data:
fun extractSVGPath(imageBitmap: ImageBitmap): String {
    val bmp = imageBitmap.asAndroidBitmap()
    val width = bmp.width
    val height = bmp.height
    var pathData = StringBuilder("M ")
    var lastX = -1
    var lastY = -1

    for (y in 0 until height) {
        for (x in 0 until width) {
            val pixel = bmp.getPixel(x, y)
            val alpha = (pixel shr 24) and 0xff
            if (alpha > 0) {
                if (lastX == -1 && lastY == -1) {
                    pathData.append("$x $y ")
                } else {
                    if (abs(x - lastX) > 1 || abs(y - lastY) > 1) {
                        pathData.append("M $x $y ")
                    } else {
                        pathData.append("L $x $y ")
                    }
                }
                lastX = x
                lastY = y
            }
        }
    }
    return pathData.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }
}

Additional Info:
Below is an example of an SVG where the path is correctly represented (this is just made up for testing):
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="350" height="150" viewBox="0 0 350 150" fill="none">
<path d="M 150.40625 41.5 L 150.40625 41.5 L 150.40625 42.5 L 150.40625 50.5 L 150.40625 59.5 L 150.40625 63.5 L 149.40625 66.5 L 148.40625 68.5 L 146.40625 69.5 L 145.40625 69.5 L 145.40625 68.5 L 145.40625 68.5 L 149.40625 68.5 L 155.40625 68.5 L 162.40625 68.5" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="none"/>
</svg>

I am open to other solutions, whether that involves a different package for drawing a signature, better ways to parse an ImageBitmap, or any other ideas.

There are lots of options for converting PNGs to SVGs, based on a Web search. You might look into what techniques they use (e.g., edge detection), see if anything is available that could work as a library, etc. See also this SO question.

@CommonsWare thanks for your comment. However, I am not looking to convert a PNG to a SVG. I've got a ImageBitmap variable im looking to extract path data out of, in code.

I understand that. However, a PNG is a bitmap. That gives you two courses of action. First, you could convert the ImageBitmap to a PNG, then use an existing PNG->SVG converter. Second, you could learn from others, see how they convert PNG bitmaps to SVG, and try applying those approaches to an ImageBitmap.
